# python beautiful soup japanese website

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse [this](https://disclosure.edinet-fsa.go.jp/E01EW/BLMainController.jsp?uji.verb=W1E63012CXW1E6A012DSPSch&uji.bean=ee.bean.parent.EECommonSearchBean&TID=W1E63013&PID=W1E63012&SESSIONKEY=1516599760245&lgKbn=1&pkbn=0&skbn=0&dskb=&dflg=0&iflg=0&row=100&idx=0&cal=2&mul=72030&fls=on&mon=&yer=&pfs=5) to download the `xblr` document. The document I am interested in is `Annual securities report - 113th period`. Inside the zip folder, there is an HTML document.

> C:\Users\smathew\Downloads\Xbrl_Search_20180124_142609.zip\S100AKEX\XBRL\PublicDoc\0104010

Once you open the link it shows a Japanese webpage. What I want is to capture data in table no 5. The problem seems that all characters are in Japanese and I am unable to identify table no 5 to get the data. I tried with `python` and `beautiful soup`. Can someone please advise me?

Thanks,
Subin

Comment: unable to open the link, can you past the contents of the link?

Comment: Correcting grammar. Added link

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Japanese page and highlight what you want to capture? I don't get what table no 5 is.